# Equivalent of "anthropomorphism" for babies

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns, analogy

*Anthropomorphism* is about attributing human emotions to other animals.

I have a one-month old baby at home, and was wondering if there was a corresponding word for attributing *adult* human emotions to infants? If I say "she looks guilty", am I being *adultomorphic*?

Comment: I think babies should have human emotions.

Comment: You need a Greek stem for *-morph-,* but ***enilikomorphism*** isn't very helpful.

Comment: [You think we shouldn’t anthropomorphize people?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sidney_Morgenbesser#Stories_and_quotations)

Comment: I just spent some time digging through a bunch of academic works on this. None of them used a single term. That doesn't mean one doesn't exist, but it may indicate that it's not in common use.

Comment: KitFox: Babies have human emotions, but they do not have all grown-up emotions, eg guilt, sexual desire, etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can perhaps call it [*personification*](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/personification) which sounds less unwieldy than *anthropomorphism*:

> the attribution of a personal nature or human characteristics to something non-human, or the representation of an abstract quality in human form

Also related is the term, [pathetic fallacy](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pathetic+fallacy?q=pathetic%20fallacy):

> the attribution of human feelings and responses to inanimate things or animals, especially in art and literature.

Here, the word *pathetic* is being used in its [archaic sense](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/pathetic).

Comment: Pathetic fallacy seem to be a good candidate, but maybe a bit too wide (it includes anthropomorphism).